Efficiently Solving a Large System of Nonlinear Equations with Singular Jacobian for Stability Analysis
I am analyzing the stability of signaling pathways modeled as a dynamic system. Specifically, I am working with a large system of nonlinear equations (approximately 100 equations). An example of the type of equations in my system is:
$$
\frac{dx_1}{dt} = k_1 x_1 - k_3 x_2 x_3 = 0
$$
$$
\frac{dx_2}{dt} = -k_3 x_1 - 3k_2 x_2 x_3 = 0
$$
$$
\frac{dx_3}{dt} = k_1 x_1 + k_2 k_3 x_1^2 = 0
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
Here, $ k_i $ are rate constants from a metabolic model, and $ x_i $ represent the concentrations of the components in the pathway.
To analyze the system, I start by linearizing the dynamic system $ \frac{dX}{dt} = F(X) $, where $ X = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N) $ and $ N \approx 100 $. The linearization around a fixed point $ X^* $ is:
$$
\frac{d (\delta X)}{dt} = J(X^*) \delta X,
$$
where $ \delta X = X - X^* $, and $ J(X^*) $ is the Jacobian matrix of $ F(X) $ evaluated at $ X^* $.
I compute $ J(X^*) $ symbolically in MATLAB, evaluate it at $ X^* $, and attempt to solve the original system $ F(X) = 0 $ using fsolve. As an initial guess, I use the result of numerically solving $ \frac{dX}{dt} = F(X) $, at the final time, with ode15s. However, I encounter significant challenges:

List item The Jacobian matrix $ J(X^*) $, which depends on $ x_i $, is consistently singular (its determinant is zero).
List item Newton's method also fails to converge due to this singularity.
List item The problem is further complicated by the large size of the system ($ N \approx 100 $).

My question is what strategies or methods can I use to efficiently solve this system of nonlinear equations given the singularity of the Jacobian? Are there numerical techniques specifically suited for large-scale systems with potentially singular Jacobians?
Any advice or references to applicable techniques would be greatly appreciated.

For a system of chemical reactions, I would expect the $k_3 x_2 x_3$ term in the first equation to be the same as the $k_3$ term in the second, etc., and not to have a term with 2 rate constants. If I am correct that these are just typos, then I generally expect the Jacobian to be singular and could write an answer about that.

@dharr Indeed, the equations I gave are just typos and I actually have around 100 equations with two types of terms, either k_i X_i or k_i X_i X_j. For me the linearity is not that much mean but yet the Jacobian is always singular which blocks me in finding of fixed point solution as well as stability analysis..

The zero eigenvalues of the Jacobian usually arise through the presence of some conservation ("mass balance") conditions that are unrelated to the stability. So for a stability analysis they can be ignored and only the non-zero eigenvalues need to be considered. However, it is possible to use the stoichiometric information about the chemical reactions to eliminate variables and find a smaller non-singular Jacobian with just the non-zero eigenvalues. Is this what you are looking for? I'm not sure it directly relates to the numerical solution of the nonlinear fixed point solution.

As a mathematician, I have some difficulties in chemistry and biology :(. That being said, I try many methods to solve F(X)=0 such as iterative methods, can't obtain convergence due to this matrix singularity. Very recently, I think I got some interesting results using Levenberg-Marquardt method, which converges and gaves different solutions depending on the initial guess I consider, when I evaluate the Jacobian in these solutions, the determinant still zero but I obtained however eigenvalues that, in real part, negative, zero, and positive. As results no conclusion about the stability :(

If you have positive real parts, then I would conclude it is unstable, but maybe you know from solving the odes it is stable.  Is that the issue? The computational science stackexchange is good for these more algorithmic things.

for the singularity of the Jacobian, I keep telling myself that since I finally obtained the eigenvalues, this is what matters. I understand that in terms of stability, only negative (real parts) eigenvalues mean stability and only positive (real parts) eigenvalues mean instability. In my case, within the 121 eigenvalues I obtained, I have negative, zero, and positive (real parts) eigenvalues at the same time. Can I conclude something in terms of stability? Also is it normal to obtain to obtain different solution depending on Initial guess passed to the algo? I am quite new at al this.. sorry

Neglecting the zeroes for the moment, if all eigenvalues have negative real parts, it is stable, and if any have positive real parts it is unstable. Levenberg-Marquart often converges to a local not necessarily global minimum if the initial guess is not close the the real solution.

I added an answer based on removing the zero eigenvalues, but now that I know your system is unstable, the key problem is that gradient-based methods won't work for unstable equilibria

@dharr your effort on the explanation of that point is much appreciated :) I will keep going in the understanding of some parts of your answer and also try to project the analysis into my case

The zero eigenvalues of the Jacobian usually arise through the presence of
some conservation ("mass balance") conditions that are unrelated to the
stability, as shown below. So for a stability analysis they can be ignored
and only the non-zero eigenvalues need to be considered. However, it is
possible to use the stoichiometric information about the chemical reactions
to eliminate variables and find a smaller non-singular Jacobian with just
the non-zero eigenvalues.
The basic idea is that if we have $S$ chemical species and $I$ independent
chemical reactions, then there must be $S-I$ conservation conditions and
these equations interrelate the different concentrations. Therefore we
can eliminate $S-I$ concentrations, and work with a smaller number of
differential equations and smaller Jacobian. This is best illustrated with a
small example, with $R=3$ chemical reactions
$$1.~\mathrm{C}+\mathrm{A}\rightleftarrows \mathrm{CA}$$
$$
2.~\mathrm{CA}+\mathrm{A}\rightleftarrows \mathrm{C}+\mathrm{A}_{2} 
$$
$$
3.~2\mathrm{CA}\rightleftarrows 2\mathrm{C}+\mathrm{A}_{2} 
$$
We have $S=4$ and choose the species order $[\mathrm{C},\mathrm{A},\mathrm{CA
},\mathrm{A}_{2}]$. The reactions have rates
$$
v_{1}=k_{1}x_{1}x_{2}-k_{-1}x_{3} 
$$
$$
v_{2}=k_{1}x_{2}x_{3}=k_{-2}x_{1}x_{4} 
$$
$$
v_{3}=k_{3}x_{3}^{2}-k_{-3}x_{1}^{2}x_{4} 
$$
The $S\times R$ stoichiometric matrix is
$$
N=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
-1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
1 & -1 & -2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
e.g., the entries in the first column indicate that for reaction 1, 1
molecule of C is consumed, 1 molecule of A is consumed, 1 molecule of CA is
produced and 0 molecules of $\mathrm{A}_{2}$ are consumed/produced. The rank
of $N$ is $I=2$ indicating that only two of the three reactions are
independent (in the sense of Hess's law): the third reaction can be written
as the second plus the reverse of the first.
There must be $S-I=2$ conservation conditions. To find these we find a basis
of the nullspace of $N^{T}$ and transpose these vectors into the rows of a $%
(S-I)\times S$ formula matrix $F$, i.e., we find $S-I$ independent left null
vectors of $N\,$
$$
F=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In this case, $F$ is easily constructed by inspection. The first row is the
number of $\mathrm{A}$ "atoms" in each species, the second is the number of $
\mathrm{C}$ atoms. (The construction via the nullspace works even if the
composition of the species is not known.). We have $FN=0$ reflecting that
each reaction is balanced in terms of the $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{C}$
atoms. If we write $c=[c_{1},c_{2},c_{3},c_{4}]^{T}$ as the initial
concentrations of the species then the conservation conditions are $Fx=Fc$.
The right-hand sides of the odes are given by $r=Nv$ with $
v=[v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}]^{T}$. The Jacobian is
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=J=NJ_{v}=N\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$
We have $rank(J)\leq rank(N)$, and since usually $I<S$, the Jacobian is
frequently singular. We consider here only the most common case where $
rank(J)=rank(N)$, which means the zero eigenvalues do not tell anything
about the stability; they arise from the presence of the conservation
conditions. (If $rank(J)<rank(N),$ then the zero eigenvalue means that
higher order terms need to be considered in the stability analysis; a linear
analysis is insufficient.).
To recast the equations with fewer variables, choose $S-I$ independent
species (i.e., their columns in $F$ are independent) to eliminate. By construction, $F$
has full row rank $S-I\,,$ so the rank of the chosen submatrix should be $S-I
$. In this case we might choose $\mathrm{CA}$ and $\mathrm{A}_{2}$ with
concentrations $w=[x_{3},x_{4}]^{T}$; the other concentrations are then $%
u=[x_{1},x_{2}]^{T}$. Partitioning $F$ conformably, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{1} & F_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ 
w
\end{bmatrix}
=F_{1}u+F_{2}w=Fc
$$
Since $F_{2}$ is nonsingular, we may solve the linear system $
F_{2}w=Fc-F_{1}u$ for $w$ in terms of $u$. Substituting in the odes, we have
a smaller system to solve. The Jacobian for this smaller system is
nonsingular and the eigenvalues are the same as the non-zero eigenvalues of
the original system.
In my experience with much smaller systems, there is not much to be gained
by moving to the smaller system, but I am not using the Jacobian to solve
the steady-state ("equilibrium point") equations $r=0$, only for the stability analysis. (I am
usually using Maple's fsolve, giving ranges to the variables; I don't know
internally which method is used, but it may be gradient-free.)
It is the nature of an unstable equilibrium point that gradient-based methods will be unsuitable to solve it.
